# aiogram timeout error on infinite polling

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiogram

Good day!

I am writing a telegram bot and using aiogram  library.
Everything seems to be working fine when I run my code.
However, if I leave the bot running for a while, after some time it throws a timeout error. Can't understand what seems to be the issue - my PC falling asleep or something else?
I run an infinite loop like this

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncio
import logging

from data import config
from utils.db_api.postgresql import Database

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s [LINE:%(lineno)d] #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    # level=logging.DEBUG,  
                    )

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
db = Database()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

the error is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 559, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 913, in start
    self._continue = None
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 721, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```